# Use variable from another script or define it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Manager class and it has lots of variables so I can reference it when I need it.

Will this reduce the performance ? or should I define it

```
public class Controller: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Manager;
}
```

```
public class GetController : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject Controller ;
   void dosomthing(){
  var Ma = Controller.Getcomponent<Controller>().Managet
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** `Getcomponent()` calls are expensive. It is OK if used once/rarely, but starts to have an effect when called continiously.

Store a reference (define) to it:

```cs
public class GetController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Will show up in unity's inspector.
    // Drag-and-Drop the gameObject with the 'Controller' component attached to it.
    [SerializeField]
    private Controller yourController ;

    void Dosomthing(){
        var Ma = yourController.Manager
    }
}
```

Also, most things in Unity can be exposed to the Inspector as long as it is serializable.

You can expose a `Controller` field to the inspector, and drag-drop the same GameObject.
This lets you skip a `GetComponent` call and another define.

Comment: Thanks, if I have too many Gameobjects with the script, drag-drop to the inspector will take lots of time. is it ok to use find in Start()?

Comment: generally a good note! Btw though it is improved a lot, in older versions they actually searched for he component, now they store a hash so access is actually pretty quick. Still of course caching is still better ;)

Comment: @forteam Yes, it is ok to do it in `Start()`;  But you are better off with a singleton, see the other answer in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72213004/7421086

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a `singleton` pattern for managers.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager singleton; // define variable as singleton

    public int score = 2; // for example...
    private void Start() => singleton = this; // setup single user class instance
}
```

And in the player class or any other class, call it without redefining it.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void AddScore() => GameManager.singleton.score += 1; // add score to manager
}
```